# Postgres jsonb data in Swift/Vapor

Tags: swift, postgresql, vapor

I have the following Vapor Fluent migration that creates a jsonb column

```
public func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return database.schema(MyModel.schema)
            .id()
            .field(.name, .custom("VARCHAR(255)"), .required)
            .field(.metadata, .custom("JSONB"), .required)
            .create()
    }
```

The model looks like this:

```
public final class MyModel: Model, Content {
    public static let schema = "blah"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    public var id: UUID?
    
    @Field(key: .metadata)
    public var metadata: Data // This is obviously wrong.
}
```

Any idea how to make Vapor retrieve and set data from to Postgres jsonb columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to use the `.json` type when declaring your field in your migration.

Here's an example I put together using the starter template code for reference:

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
}

final class Todo: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "todos"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Field(key: "metadata")
    var metadata: [String: String]
    
    @Field(key: "person")
    var person: Person

    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil, metadata: [String: String], person: Person) {
        self.id = id
        self.metadata = metadata
        self.person = person
    }
}
```

I declared two Fields, `metadata` and `person`.

```
struct CreateTodo: Migration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return database.schema("todos")
            .id()
            .field("metadata", .json, .required)
            .field("person", .json, .required)
            .create()
    }


    func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return database.schema("todos").delete()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JSONB (Vapor 4)

The best of both worlds - JSONB in Postgres and type-safety here:

1. Declare a database column of type `.custom("JSONB")` in the migration
2. Define a data model for your JSON data
3. Use your data model as a type for the respective property of the Fluent model.

You get serialization / deserialization out of the box.

Working (tested) example:

```
struct CreateTodo: AsyncMigration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema("todos")
            .id()
            .field("details", .custom("JSONB"), .required)
            .create()
    }

    func revert(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema("todos").delete()
    }
}

struct Details: Content {
    var itemA: String
    var itemB: String
}

final class Todo: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "todos"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "details")
    var details: Details

    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil, details: Details) {
        self.id = id
        self.details = details
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
curl localhost:8080/todos
[{"id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001","details":{"itemA":"A","itemB":"B"}}]
```

Functional sample repo: https://github.com/ruslanvs/JSONBSample